# SharedPreferences doesn't save values

Tags: android, multithreading, save, sharedpreferences

for some reason SharedPreferences doesn't save the values, the code is in a service...

```
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.not_local_sp), MODE_PRIVATE);
            long lastExecuted = sharedPref.getLong(getString(R.string.timeDone), 0L);
            int scanInterval = 500 * 60 * 60;

            while (true) {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastExecuted >= scanInterval && contextCreator == null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "inside while loop");
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastExecuted));
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(lastExecuted));
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(scanInterval));
                    contextCreator = new ProtectionContextCreator();
                    feature = AppScanFactory.createAppScan(getBaseContext());
                    feature.add(new BoostFeature(getBaseContext(), new StubScanStore()));
                    contextCreator.create(getBaseContext(), feature.getType(), NotificationService.this);

                    /*Shared pref*/

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putLong(getString(R.string.timeDone), System.currentTimeMillis());
                    editor.commit();
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
```

the lastExecuted variable always get the default value, 0.

Comment: how do you know that is not saving it ?

Comment: I'm assuming, cuz i'm not getting the value

Comment: you have an infinite loop (`while(true)`) but you are reading the value outside it

Comment: are you sure that it executes the code that should save it? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: I am sure it executes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an infinite loop (`while(true)`) but you are reading the value outside it

this line

```
long lastExecuted = sharedPref.getLong(getString(R.string.timeDone), 0L)
```

should be inside the while loop (if you are using `lastExecuted` to check if the value was stored)